# Count Annotations on MapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

After completing a loop that places annotations on a map from an array, I want to count the number of annotations.

My code as follows:

```
let anCount = self.mapView.annotations?.count
            if (anCount > 1) {
//do something
            }
```

gives error:

> Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
>   'Int'

The fixit suggestions yield other errors.  What is the correct way to count the number of annotations for the map.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Value+of+optional+type%22+%22must+be+unwrapped%22

Comment: By the way, be careful of just counting at `annotations` because there might be different types of annotations. E.g., including or excluding the user location on the map (which results in a system generated [`MKUserLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkuserlocation) to be added on your behalf) will suddenly change this logic. You really should filter the results for annotations of a particular type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unwrap the optional, e.g. with `if let`, which you can then combine with the `> 1` test in a single `if` statement:

```
if let anCount = mapView.annotations?.count, anCount > 1 {
    //do something
}
```

But `annotations` isn't an optional (at least in current iOS versions), so you'd probably just do:

```
let anCount = mapView.annotations.count
if anCount > 1 {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer which worked but did you downvote my question cause I took too long to respond?  I had a lot going on. In theory, optionals should be simple, but in practice if you are still learning them, each case can be different.

Comment: No, I did not down vote. I was merely suggesting that you research more before posting a question. If you are going to post a question that has been asked before, it’s good to include references of a question or two to demonstrate that you did research it.